# asp:gridview taking too long to load

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

**What I want:** I have a table with 10k rows and and about 30 cols. Database is Oracle. I want to link to a `asp:gridview`.

**Issue**: it takes 2 mins to load the data. I need to redue the time to 1 or 2 secs. following line is causing this issue:  `GridView1.DataBind()`

**Debug**: after doing some google research. I understand that its not a good idea to load 10k records at same time. so to fix this I added a pagging as shown below. however it still takes 2 mins

How can I redue the load time?

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        BindGridData()
    End If
End Sub


Protected Sub BindGridData()
    Dim sqlConn1 As New OdbcConnection(myConnectionString1)
    Try
        sqlConn1.Open()
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
        Dim adapter As OdbcDataAdapter

         Dim Query1 As String = "SELECT * FROM MyTable "
        adapter = New OdbcDataAdapter(Query1, sqlConn1)
         
        adapter.Fill(ds, "myDataSet")
        Dim i As Integer = ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count
        CountL.Text = i & " Records"
        Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables("myDataSet")
        Session("SaveData") = dt
        GridView1.DataSource = Session("SaveData")
        GridView1.DataBind()

        sqlConn1.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return
    End Try
End Sub


Protected Sub GridView1_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewPageEventArgs)
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    GridView1.DataSource = Session("SaveData")
    GridView1.DataBind()
   End Sub
```

Comment: Studies show you never really want more than about 2K unfiltered records. Beyond that, and human brains don't really process them well in terms of understanding what's actually in the set, _even with paging_. Instead, have the user provide an initial search filter that narrows the results to something they have a reasonable chance to actually process.

Comment: Also, the connection should be in a `Using` block.

Comment: Finally, the basic solution here depends on what kind of database you're talking to, because the paging features within the database itself are different depending on what kind it is. You also don't want all that data using up memory again for **each session** on your web server.

Comment: If you really want 10k rows, disable the `ViewState` of the GridView. This will reduce the page size substantially (and thus loading times). But how much time does the query take when you access it with a DB program directly?

Comment: 10,000 rows is way too large to pull into a data table. And even MORE worse is then shoving that data table into session (you don't want to do that - that's too large for session and is going to gobble up too much server resources). Also, as noted, what database system are you  using? In the case of SQL-server, you can use what is called server side data paging, and this can work very well for your needs.  If your data base does not support paging, then your design requires a change, and I can see/find no reason to pull 10,000 rows without first filtering.

Comment: See my post below with a working data paging example. Even with 12 million rows in the example, the page change is WELL UNDER 1 second...

Answer (score 1):

You should easy be able to get this time down to less then 1 second. In fact, any page that takes longer then 1 second to respond suggests that something is already very wrong in regards to the web page design and code behind.

It should not matter if your database table has 2 rows, or 20 million rows, the time for the web page to respond should be kept below 1 second. Web pages taking more then just 2 seconds to load are far too long of delays, and this results in a poor user experience when using such web sites. (such sites are painful for users).

The other issue is mostly a UI design issue. How can a user deal with, read, and have to page though 10,000 records? This does not seem possible. Even with a data pager, this amounts to a whopping 500 data pages!  A user hitting the next button every 4 seconds would require a whopping 41 minutes to view the data!

Users really can't deal with such a volume of data, then why throw 10,000 rows of data at the user and torture them?

Keep in mind that we need to deal with 2 issues here for performance.

First, we have to limit the data pulled from the SQL server (Oracle) in this example.

Second, we have to limit the data sent to the web page to achieve good performance.

The data pager can thus "break up" the data pulled into smaller pages, but PAGERS CAN NOT reduce number of records pulled from the database server.

The data pager can work if you say pull 300 rows, and then display 20 at one time on the web page. This speeds up the web page, and reduces the HTML markup sent to the web page, since we sent only 20 rows to the browser at one time.

So, the data pager approach works up to about a max of 200-300 records. With larger row counts then we need to start reducing data pulled from the database server. The goal here is thus to reduce both the HTML markup sent to the browser, and also reduce data pulled from the database into that data table.

Loading 1000 rows into a data table means we already loaded way too much data here. This not only slows down the web server, uses large amounts of memory, but all these issues are multiplied by each user browsing on the system!

With just 10 users on the web site, we now pulled 100,000 rows of data, and such data loads don't result in anything of value for the end user. Well, perhaps the end result of forcing user's to spend time in a prison of 10,000 rows to try and read.

So, the built in data pager? It is of practical use for about 300 rows pulled. Any more rows than that, then we need a different approach.

In other words, we need to grasp what Google, Microsoft, Amazon and even companies that don’t even create software ask potential employees they are going to hire.

Such companies ask questions of the type of "scale" in regards to "how big" or "how far" or “how many”. This is a skill set employers are looking for.

So, in code you can pull 10,000 rows and try to display such data. However, that's simply too big, too much and too many rows for a given user to see or deal with. So, always keep in mind these issues of how big, or how far, or how many.

So, with a sense of scale, then we find about a max of around 300 records can be used with the built in data pager. After that, we have to change the approach to reduce the pain for the user, and also reduce server-side resources used.

So, let's do a pager example with a small table of 12 million rows. Let's get the response time down WELL below 1 second. However, while below follows a working proof of concept, I do apologize to the community here, since it still beyond a bad idea to send or force the user to try and deal with 10,000 rows of data – it just not a practical UI at all here. Obviously in these cases, I would provide some type of filtering system to allow the user to limit the data rows pulled in the first place. So, while the posted solution below is blistering fast, it still not a great UI idea (to present user's with so much data).

So, the solution is to dump use of the data pager, and roll your own. With a custom data pager, then we ONLY pull the rows from the database for the given page, and we thus don't pull 10,000 rows and avoid a cache of such rows in memory. Only pulling 20 rows from the database? Well, 20 rows is small and very fast performance wise.

As a FYI you REALLY but REALLY do not want to save/store the resulting database pull of that 10,000 row data table into session(). Again, way too large, way too much memory, and the transfer of data into session will often take as much time as re-pulling the data from the database!

Regardless, as suggested, we not going to pull all the records anymore anyway, and thus we will not bother or need to save the resulting data in session anyway.

So, the solution here is to use database server paging, and not data table paging (and pulling all records).

The example below is for T-SQL SQL server, and Oracle also supports such paging, but the SQL syntax will of course be different, as all vendors of SQL database systems have their own flavors of SQL syntax for paging the SQL query.

Since you did not tag this question with Oracle, then not a huge deal, and this example uses T-SQL and SQL server. The following is thus a proof of concept, and will work for any of the major database systems with some changes for the given flavor of SQL you are using in regards to data paging.

So, here is our markup:

```
        <div style="float:left">
            <asp:Button ID="cmdLoad" runat="server" 
                Text="Load database million rows"
                OnClick="cmdLoad_Click"      
                CssClass="myshadow"
                />
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;margin-left:25px">
            Database row count = 
            <asp:Label ID="lblRows" runat="server" Text="">
            </asp:Label>
        </div>

        <br />
        <br />
        <br />

        <asp:GridView ID="GVHistory" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover" 
            Width="50%">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DateStamp" HeaderText="Date" 
                    DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt}" ItemStyle-Width="160px" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyEmployeeID" HeaderText="Emp ID" ItemStyle-Width="80px" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ComputerNetworkName" HeaderText="Computer Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Note" HeaderText="Notes" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <br />

        <asp:LinkButton ID="cmdPrevious" runat="server" 
            CssClass="myshadow" style="float:left"
            OnClick="cmdPrevious_Click" >
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-lg"> Previous</i>
        </asp:LinkButton>

        <asp:Label ID="lblPageOn" runat="server" Text="1"
            style="float:left;margin-left:20px;margin-right:10px;font-size:x-large">
        </asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="lblOn" runat="server" Text="of"
            style="float:left;font-size:x-large">
        </asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="lblNumPages" runat="server" Text="22"
            style="float:left;margin-left:10px;margin-right:20px;font-size:x-large">
        </asp:Label>


        <asp:LinkButton ID="cmdNext" runat="server" 
            CssClass="myshadow" style="float:left"
            OnClick="cmdNext_Click" >
            &nbsp;&nbsp;Next&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-lg"></i>
        </asp:LinkButton>
```

And code behind:

```
Const PagerSize = 18


Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        ' Get one time row count from database
        Dim rst = MyRst("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo_ContactHistory", My.Settings.AxisMIS)
        lblRows.Text = rst.Rows(0)(0)
        cmdLoad.Text = $"Load {rst.Rows(0)(0):N0} rows of data"


    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub cmdLoad_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    ' Setup our custom data paging
    Dim intPages As Integer = lblRows.Text / PagerSize
    lblPageOn.Text = 1
    lblNumPages.Text = intPages

    LoadGrid()


End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    ' load database based on current page number setting

    Dim iOnPage As Integer = lblPageOn.Text

    Dim strSQL As String =
        "SELECT * FROM dbo_ContactHistory ORDER BY dbo_ContactHistory.DateStamp
        OFFSET ((@PageNumber - 1) * @RowsPerPage) ROWS
        FETCH NEXT @RowsPerPage ROWS ONLY;"

    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL)
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@PageNumber", SqlDbType.Int).Value = iOnPage
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@RowsPerPage", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PagerSize

    Dim rstData As DataTable = MyRstP(cmdSQL, My.Settings.AxisMIS)
    GVHistory.DataSource = rstData
    GVHistory.DataBind()

End Sub

Protected Sub cmdPrevious_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim iPageOn As Integer = lblPageOn.Text
    If iPageOn > 1 Then
        iPageOn = iPageOn - 1
        lblPageOn.Text = iPageOn
    End If

    LoadGrid()

End Sub

Protected Sub cmdNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim iPageOn As Integer = lblPageOn.Text
    If iPageOn < lblNumPages.Text Then
        iPageOn = iPageOn + 1
        lblPageOn.Text = iPageOn
    End If

    LoadGrid()


End Sub
```

And the result looks like this:

[image]

Note in above how the page loads instant. And I mean 100% absolute instant. By the time I have lifted the mouse button the page already has loaded. And even with a table of 12 million rows, the response time is instant without any perceptible delay.

And here is a screen cap of data paging, and once again, despite having 65,000+ data pages (to torture the user), a click on next or previous data page is again 100% instant, and without delay. Of course, the user having to page though 65,000 data pages? Well, as noted, not a great idea from a user point of view.

Using next/previous:

[image]

Also, in above I used 2 helper routines, and they simply return a data table. The 2 routines did use the .net SqlProvider for SQL server, but such code could/would be just fine with the odbc provider:

```
Public Function MyRst(strSQL As String, Optional strCon As String = "") As DataTable
    ' general get any data from SQL

    If strCon = "" Then
        strCon = GetConStr()    ' my defualt connection string
    End If
    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(strCon)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            rstData.TableName = strSQL
        End Using
    End Using
    Return rstData
End Function

Public Function MyRstP(cmdSQL As SqlCommand, Optional strCon As String = "") As DataTable
    ' general get any data from SQL command
    If strCon = "" Then strCon = GetConStr()

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(strCon)
        Using (cmdSQL)
            cmdSQL.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using

    Return rstData

End Function
```

Comment: I would like to use `GridView1_PageIndexChanging` method, rather than creating your own pagging from sctract?

Comment: The built in data pager is not all that great, and as I stated, I would say about a max of 300 rows is all the built in pager is good for. The built in pager works fine up to about 300 rows, since then while you each page time are pulling 300 rows, only say 20 are sent to the client side, and thus it runs quite well. As I stated, the  goal is to reduce rows sent to the browser side, but when you have more then say 300 rows, then you ALSO need to page to the database. As you can see, with 12 million rows, the speed is absolute instant without ANY perceptible delay. In other words, it is fast!

Comment: Not much extra work for my custom pager. and amount of code used for the "roll your own" data pager was not much more code then built in data pager anyway.  Whole point here was super high performance.  I suppose it might be possible to use both SQL server data paging and then also the built in data pager. The issue is built in data pager ALWAYS works against the full data set, and that is too high cost since each page change results in a full pull of the dataset in question. I not looked close, but if the built in pager allows setting number of pages, or row count, then it could be used.

Comment: Let me take a quick look at the built in pager. If it can be feed the number of pages, or rows, but we only pull the one page of data from SQL server, then it could be used. So, I just not 100% sure we can use the built in pager for this. Rememer, in my example, I have 12 million rows, and 640,000 pages as my pager shows. So, I not all that sure the built in pager would help, since we certainly not going to show 640,000 buttons for each page. As noted, let me look at the pager and see if it's possbile